# Reading two files, a csv and xls, and bring columns from csv to xls based on subnet(csv)/ip(xls) match

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, csv, subnet

I am trying to make a program that reads two files, a csv and xls, and use some python logic that parses and transfers certain columns from the csv to xls, based on a ip/subnet match.

The csv has subnet, mask, and cidr, in columns B,C, and D. (csv has about 10k rows, not all will be used.)

The xls has ip address in column C. (xls has 5009 rows), each ip address corresponds to the subnet it is in.

For example, this info in csv colB,C,D:

```
subnet        mask          cidr
10.120.10.0  255.255.255.0  /24
```

corresponds to, this info in xls colB(these ip's aren't consecutive. they're on random rows.)

```
10.120.10.12
10.120.10.13
```

The columns in csv I need to port to the xls file are G, H, I, K, and M.

I'm trying to find a way to match each ip in the xls file to a subnet in the csv, and bring the data in csv columns G, H, I, K, and M to the row of the corresponding ip in the xls.

Sorry if this is confusing, it's a confusing problem to solve and i'm just a beginner to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with you could try this script

```
import openpyxl
from xlrd import open_workbook
import csv

#To read XLX

book = open_workbook('IPADR.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
keys = [sheet.cell(row_index, 0).value for row_index in xrange(sheet.nrows)]
print keys

# To read Csv 

exampleFile = open('sample.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
for row in exampleReader:
        print row[0]
```

Comment: Problem is, the file is not xlsx its xls. I tried openpyxl but it does not work with xls format.

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-python-parse-spreadsheet-data/

You may try this

       import xlrd
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('my_file_name.xls')
 worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name('My_Sheet_Name')
 sheet.cell(0, 0).value